# If $f$ has a local minimum at $x=-1$.Then find the set of possible values of $b.$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:R\to R$ be defined by $$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             b-2x  & ,x\leq-1
             \\ 2x+3 &x>-1
             \end{array}
   \right.$$If $f$ has a local minimum at $x=-1$.Then find the set of possible values of $b.$

---

Before $x=-1$,$f(x)$ is a decreasing linear function and after $x=-1$,$f(x)$ is a increasing linear function.Value $f(-1)=b+2$
I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: In order to speak of a function having a local extremum, it at the very least needs to be continuous at that point. If you invoke continuity at $x=-1$, what do you get?

Comment: Well that is strange, but I get what they mean now that I know the answer. It's a bit wonky in this case since $f$ is not differentiable at $-1$, but the left and right hand derivatives exist. From the left, it is negative; from the right, it is positive. This is true regardless of what $b$ is. This tells you that if there is any local extremum, it must be a minimum. Since $x=-1$ corresponds to the $b-2x$ part, it is actually a minimum when $b-2x$ lies below $2x+3$. This corresponds to $b \le -1$. Personally I would not use the term "local minimum" since it suggests calculus, but..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $$f_b(x)>1\quad(x>-1), \quad \lim_{x\searrow-1}f_b(x)=1, \quad f_b(x)>f_b(-1)=b+2\quad(x<-1)\ .$$
A glance at a figure then makes it obvious that $f_b$ has a local minimum at $x=-1$ if $b+2\leq1$, i.e., $b\leq-1$, and has no local minimum at $x=-1$ if $b+2>1$, i.e., $b>-1$.